# Does unset before the assignment matter?

Tags: php, symfony

```
class RouteCollection implements \IteratorAggregate, \Countable
{
    /**
     * @var Route[]
     */
    private $routes = array();

    public function add($name, Route $route)
    {
        unset($this->routes[$name]);

        $this->routes[$name] = $route;
    }

     public function remove($name)
     {
        foreach ((array) $name as $n) {
            unset($this->routes[$n]);
        }
     }
}
```

This is a piece of code from the class `Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection`. Does unset before the assignment matter?

Why is it done?

Second question: Why in remove method simple string is parsed to array?

Why I can't use simply:

```
unset($this->routes[$name]);
```

Same as in add method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does unset before the assignment matter?*

It can. If `$this->routes[$name]` is a PHP reference and you don't use `unset`, all symbols pointing to the underlying value will point to the new value. If you use `unset` before, the assignment will only affect the symbol used.

*Second question: Why in remove method simple string is parsed to array?*

This is just a small trick that allows you to use the `remove` method with both strings and array. When you cast a string (e.g. `'abc'`) to an array, PHP will return an array that contains the string as its only value (`array(0 => 'abc')`). For strings the method works as you suggested, and for arrays it will unset all names in the array.